# How can I force the __utmz cookie to be set on the first page load

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I am using a sweet little function to track visitors to my site and dump the info to Salesforce.  However many form submissions have (none) set for many values because (as I understand it) the cookie is not set until the second page load.

I have tested this and that seems to be accurate, the problem is many people fill out a form on the first page, and I don't get any info through these submissions.

I am loading GA as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-29066630-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 
        'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    ga.setAttribute('async', 'true');
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(ga);
  })();


</script>
```

And then running a php function to parse the __utmz cookie apart:

```
function tracking_cookie() { // ver 1.5
    $trackarr   = split('[|]',$_COOKIE["__utmz"]);
    $conversion = $_COOKIE["Conversion"];

    for($i=0;$i<count($trackarr);$i++){
        $keyvalues=split('[=]',$trackarr[$i]);
        $key=substr($keyvalues[0],-6);      
        switch ($key){
            case "utmcsr":
                $cookie['SearchEngine']     =   $keyvalues[1];break;
            case "utmccn":
                $cookie['SearchCampaign']   =   $keyvalues[1];break;
            case "utmcmd":
                $cookie['SearchType']       =   $keyvalues[1];break;
            case "utmcct":
                $cookie['AdText']           =   $keyvalues[1];break;
            case "utmctr":
                $cookie['Keyword']          =   $keyvalues[1];break;
            case "mgclid":
                $cookie['isPPC']            =   $keyvalues[1];break;
        }
    }
```

I have more code running after this.  Any ideas on how to force the cookie to load the first time around?

Comment: Aren't the `_utmz` values passed in from a linked tag? Couldn't you just get the values from the tagged link on first load?

Comment: What do you mean?  linked tag?  These visitors are organic and ppc not just ppc.

Comment: What do you do with the cookies after you parsed them on `tracking_cookie()`? Do you set them as session variables? When and how to do you send these data to salesforce? Your question needs more information

Comment: I am not sure the question does need more info... It doesn't matter what I do with the info once it is set.  My issue was that it wasn't being set until the second page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie isn't readable until the second page load - because they get sent in the request.

What you could do is on the initial page load (and no _utmz cookie is found in PHP) append another JS file / invoke some JS that will run an ajax command back to your server after the page has loaded.

This will act as the second page load and should have access to the new cookie (and the user wouldn't have left the page)

Comment: this looks like a great answer.  I solved the problem by turning on auto tagging in Adwords so that any click coming in from adwords has GCLID in the url.  if GCLID then is a PPC, if __utmz is set to PPC then its a PPC else its an Organic

Answer (score -1):

Have you taken a look at this Force.com Toolkit for Google Analytics?  May be more reliable to get the information right from Google.  Without knowing what else you are tracking or how you are storing it in Salesforce it is hard to give more detail.

https://github.com/mavens/Force.com-Toolkit-for-Google-Analytics

There is also some discussion on Google Groups - http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-tracking-and-implementation-issues/bVR84di07pQ

You did say, "Many form submissions have none", so does that mean you do get data from time to time?  Can you narrow it down to a browser?

Comment: I am handling the accessing of this information in PHP and then assigning it to hidden fields which propogate into SF when the form submits.  Its a web to lead form.  From my research, the __utmz cookie does not always get set until the 2nd site click.  You can go to the homepage but it won't set till you click on another page or refresh the current page...